# Kong API Gateway - Domain Restriction

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress, konga

I have a Service that is mapped to a consumer, and I want to allow the Service Routes to the specific domain name.

We have a plugin to restrict the IP https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/ip-restriction/.

is there any way to restrict the domain?

Comment: What do you call restrict the domain ?

Comment: Example: 
www.example1.com can consume the service, 
any other domains should not be allowed to consume the service.

Comment: Ok, so more a  fully qualified domain name to be pedantic. The issue is that for a client you only know the ip, and the reverse ip to fqdn is not working well. And lot of IP are shared. So the simple solution you resolve the domain or ask the up and set the ip on your plugin. some domain will answer different ip to load balance so hard to do it without asking the owner